# Remove suffixes from words in a string that are only less than 8 characters long

Tags: python

```
def removeSuffixs(sentence):
    line = sentence.split()

    new_line = []
    string_index_list = []
    string_length_list = []
    suffix_list = ['ed', 'ly', 'ing'] 

    for i in line:
        string_index = line.index(i)
        string_index_list.append(string_index)

        string_length = len(line[string_index])
        string_length_list.append(string_length)


    for x in line:
        for suff in suffix_list:
            for s in string_length_list:
                if x.endswith(suff) and s < 8:
                    x = x.removesuffix(suff)
                else:
                    pass
        new_line.append(x)
        new_line2 = ' '.join(new_line)

    return new_line2

print(removeSuffixs('a boy is jumping quickly tremendously'))
```

The output is:

```
a boy is jump quick tremendous
```

How do I add a conditional that will only remove the suffix from strings that are less than 8 characters long so that my output will be `a boy is jump quick tremendously`?

Comment: Do you know how to add conditionals? Do you know how to split a sentence into words? Do you know how to get the length of a string?

Comment: You may want to try your code on a string like `'Fling the bed at the fly.'` Or even `'I can edit and binge like a lyricist'`.

Comment: I have updated my code to include conditionals and splitting a sentence into words, also getting the length of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to split the sentence into words, then get the length of the word you are changing, like this:

```
def removeSuffixs(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    suffixList = ["ed", "ly", "ing"] #add more as necessary
    output_list = []
    for word in words:
        final_word = word
        for suffix in suffixList:
            if suffix in word and len(word)<8:
                final_word = word.replace(suffix, '')
        output_list.append(final_word)
    return ' '.join(output_list)
```

first, I'm splitting the sentence into a list of words. Then looping through those words to check every single one for their length and whether they contain the suffix.
At the end we're returning the ready sentence using .join() function of string.

I've also changed *item* to *suffix* so the code is easier to read :)

Comment: Note that your code doesn't check that the suffix is actually at the _end_ of the word. To test try `removeSuffixs('edpy')`

Comment: Thanks! This actually works if i use word.removesuffix(suffix) instead of word.replace(suffix, ' ')

Comment: You'll also want to `break` out of the inner loop if the condition is met. And check if `word.endswith(suffix)` rather than `suffix in word`.

Answer (score 0):

A generator expression and regular expressions make this quite straightforward. For each word in the sentence we either return the word if it's 8 characters long or longer, or we substitute `ly` or `ing` for nothing using `re.sub`. Then we use `str.join` to bring it back into a sentence.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'a boy is jumping quickly tremendously'
>>> ' '.join(
...   w if len(w) >= 8 else \
...   re.sub(r'(ed|ly|ing)$', '', w)
...   for w in s.split()
... )
'a boy is jump quick tremendously'
```

If you don't want to hard-code in the suffixes, you can have them as a list and compile a regular expression based on joining them with `|`.

```
>>> import re
>>> suffixes = ['ed', 'ly', 'ing']
>>> regex = re.compile(f"({'|'.join(suffixes)})$")
>>> s = 'a boy is jumping quickly tremendously'
>>> ' '.join(
...   w if len(w) >= 8 else \
...   regex.sub('', w)
...   for w in s.split()
... )
'a boy is jump quick tremendously'
```

Comment: if you try s = 'edpy' you also get the same issue as the solution below since this is not checking for suffixes at the end of the word

Comment: Edited to correct. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hey Chris, can I ask you what wrapping ed| ly | ing in parentheses did or changed to the original code? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of being `ed` or `ly` or `ing$` it groups those three suffixes and then adds the end of line marker.